# MVC - Entity framework - Metadata relation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, metadata

Today I've been working with MVC for the first time. Also normally I use the EF with model first, but I wanted to try POCO.

So I've made my 3 entities and when I try to make a controller I get an error:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for "BookExchange.Models.Exchange". Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types "BookExchange.Models.Exchange" and "BookExchange.Models.Book". The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

My 3 classes:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ISBN10 { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public virtual Exchange Exchange { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exchange> Exchanges { get; set; }
}

public class Exchange
{
    [Key]
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I don't want to lose the association properties.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may need to add FK properties.

Comment: I have no idea where. Got any tips on that? And how to declare them.

Comment: remove this: "public virtual Exchange Exchange { get; set; }" in Book or  "public virtual Book Book { get; set; }" in Exchange. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding foreign key properties for your references. E.g.

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ISBN10 { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Exchange Exchange { get; set; }
    public int ExchangeID { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exchange> Exchanges { get; set; } 
}

public class Exchange
{
    public int ExchangeID { get; set; }

    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
}
```

Also, take a look at [ScottGu's post on code first](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) and [this EF post on conventions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx).

Comment: I just copied and pasted all of your code into the classes. And get the following error when trying to add a controller: "Unable to retrieve metadata for 'BookExchange.Models.Person'. Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'BookExchange.Models.Exchange'and 'BookExchange.Models.Book'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: EF tries to infer your relationships based on a naming convention. In this case, BookID is the FK for Book in Exchange. However, Person.OwnedBooks and Person.RentedBooks can't be inferred because they don't follow the convention. You can either change them to Person.Books and Person.Exchanges or map them explicitly with the Fluent API or data annotations attributes.

Comment: This is not the problem. I changed them to Books and Exchanges but this didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Remove database, so EF will create new)

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Exchange Exchange { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exchange> Exchanges { get; set; }
}

public class Exchange
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your one on one associations.

Remove one reference between exchange or book, so Code-first can decide which one is more important in your one on one relation (Book <--> Exchange)

If you want to know why, [you should read this:](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx)